# Logged off error with Ajax and header redirect

Tags: php, ajax, security, authentication, http-headers

I am trying to make something where if a user tries to execute a function in my system when they are not logged in, it will popup a message saying they can't do it because they  aren't logged in. They are then sent to the login screen when they press ok.

I also want it to redirect users back to the login screen if they type the url in directly, but this time without an error message.

I have:

```
$components = explode('/', $url, 3) ;

if(!isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $components[0] != 'access' && $components[0] != 'login')
    {

        echo json_encode('{"error": 2000, "msg": "You must be logged in to do that."}') ;
        return false ;
}
```

Which is fine for Ajax, but wouldn't work if the url was typed in. The $components[0] != 'access' etc is to just stop this condition executing if the user is on the login screen.

How can I do this without the header location effecting the Ajax call and also not simply echoing the error message when the user visits a forbidden url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I do this without the header location effecting the Ajax call and also not simply echoing the error message when the user visits a forbidden url?

There are multiple ways to achieve this, let's discuss two here:

## Check the referer

First of all, you could check the HTTP referer, browsers sends the URL of the page which linked to the current page as HTTP header.

Take a look at this (shortened) HTTP request to `http://foo.invalid/blah/?action=newfolder.php`, when a user clicks on a form/link.

#### Request

```
Request URL:http://foo.invalid/blah/?action=newfolder.php
Request Method:POST
```

#### Headers

```
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Host:foo.invalid
Referer:http://foo.invalid/
```

You can see that there is the "Referer" field, if a user opens directly `http://foo.invalid/blah/?action=newfolder.php`, there won't be the referer field.

#### Source

```
<?php 
if (empty($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) {
    // Redirect to login (Referer empty)
} else {
    // Show JSON warning (Referer not empty)
}
?>
```

However, this solution is *not* that reliable, as some users disable or fake the referer for privacy reasons.

## Add a custom HTTP header field

A better way would be to send a custom HTTP header, please note that you can only add custom HTTP headers to AJAX requests. Some libraries like [JQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) already add the custom header for you.

#### Source ([XMLHttpRequest](http://www.w3.org/TR/2006/WD-XMLHttpRequest-20060405/#dfn-setrequestheader))

```
var r = new XMLHttpRequest();
r.open('get', '/blah/?action=newfolder.php');
r.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
r.send(null);
```

Now the request will contain the custom `X-Requested-With` header, if the header is missing you can assume that the page was opened by entering the URL.

```
<?php 
if (empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'])) {
    // Redirect to login (X-Requested-With empty)
} else {
    // Show JSON warning (X-Requested-With not empty)
}
?>
```

Comment: I like the sound of the custom header idea, I'll give it a try tomorrow and let you know how it goes!

Answer (score -1):

```
$UserName = "username";
$PassWord = "password";

if ($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] != $UserName || $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'] != $PassWord) {
        header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="My Realm"');
        header('HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized');
        die('Your username and password is incorrect');
                    // or you can redirect user if username or password is incorrect
                header("Location:"your redirecting url);              
}
```

Please use this code it might be helpful to you....

To learn more about authentication in php see below link:

http://php.net/manual/features.http-auth.php